# How do I append JSON entries to CSV file under columns with the same names as the keys?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, data-science

This is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

response = requests.get(f'https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017,10000&bedrooms=11700,11701,11702,11703,11704,11705,11706,11707,11708,11709,11710&city=4320&page=2&groupstart=30&offset=0&maxOffset=248&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017,10000&isNRI=N&multiLang=en')
df = pd.json_normalize(response.json()['resultList'], max_level=0)
df.to_csv('property_data.csv', mode='a')

for i in range(3, 102):
    response = requests.get(f'https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017,10000&bedrooms=11700,11701,11702,11703,11704,11705,11706,11707,11708,11709,11710&city=4320&page={i}&groupstart={30 * (i - 1)}&offset=0&maxOffset=248&sortBy=premiumRecent&postedSince=-1&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022,10001,10017,10000&isNRI=N&multiLang=en')
    df = pd.json_normalize(response.json()['resultList'])
    df.to_csv('property_data.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

An issue I am encountering while appending to the property_data.csv file is that due to the non existence certain keys in JSON file, data from different columns is getting mixed up.

eg:

```
df = pd.read_csv("property_data.csv", on_bad_lines='skip')
df['floorNo'].unique()
```

produces the result

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
array([nan, '9', '38', '12', '10', '17', '16', '48', '28', '3', '15',
       '35', '5', '30', '21', '27', '45', '11', 'Lift', 'Air Conditioned',
       'Private jaccuzi', 'Jogging and Strolling Track', 'North - East',
       'South -West', 'East', 'West', 'South', 'North', 'South - East',
       'ABAMNC', 'MCGM', 'Water Availability 24 Hours Available',
       'Water Availability 6 Hours Available',
       'Water Availability 12 Hours Available',
       'Water Availability 1 Hour Available', '800', '355', '550', '507',
       '250', '750', '1310', '1620', '1295', '650', '1012', '600', '2000',
       '555', '775', '920', '1095', '882', '1500', '630', '1100', '699',
       '900', '540', 'Intercom Facility', '71353', '68345', '77877',
       '56356', '54016', '68703', '64595',
       'ff260c41-dd5c-44a1-866f-c9cedca191e8graj6227',
       '96de2716-6a3a-488f-a34c-f01563544696ghar1657',
       '5d6b1f8e-73a4-4439-a956-c4c8367e8bd7raje3800',
       '9f75a3cd-f749-42aa-bc77-39ef9d2ad8c7yoge1410',
       '0955f6a3-f09e-417b-a2e1-8332b6d467f0vaid3337',
       'b2ce8fad-2392-4b26-95d9-edaf4bf46cddkhuz5152',
       '6e729b73-e20b-4b43-832d-30cef3094fc4chan8207',
       'b09c339d-5667-4095-a756-b54356a44ddckash6262',
       '50abb073-dfdd-4e24-b544-712b6d8bcc43bina7067',
       '58d5ac1c-cdb3-4542-96c3-581b3a9fb8d1meha4330',
       '35d87e1a-5dfd-4c8f-9192-0acbb8d36d60hari1100',
       '53d875a6-1074-443e-b7d7-a1cb55f63d6anila1380',
       '3cad0738-bdf0-4f1b-81f3-4bb890a16e77scsh5048', '+91-81XXXXXXX88',
...
       'prathamesh apartments, Matunga East, Mumbai', 'Bhandup',
       '40 X 100 sqft sqft', 'Freehold', 'Co-operative Society',
       'Power Back Up', 'Near Sitladevi Temple, Kotak Mahindra Bank',
       'Near Lodha World School', 'Newly Constructed Property',
       'Near Mohan Baug Banquet hall', 'Smart Home'], dtype=object)
```

How do I make it so that the data is appended to the correct column on the csv file and if the file does not have a certain column, we create a new one and set values of other entries to null?

Comment: Try providing columns attribute 

df = df.to_csv('property_data.csv', mode='a', header=False, columns=['a', 'b'])

When you specify columns, if column does not exist in that row, automatically NaN/null is assigned

Comment: I put the required column names in the columns parameter but I am getting this error:
KeyError: "['luxAmenMap', 'nonluxAmenMap'] not in index"